# Object.values and finally use a flat not working in IE

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON , with different Arrays  as shown and creating a final  Array as shown

```
const jsonData = {
    "Colleges": {
        "GMR": [{
            "studentname": "peter",
            "address": "green woods",
            "admissionnumber": "55667"

        }, {
            "studentname": "paul",
            "address": "antonio",
            "admissionnumber": "66654"

        }],

        "vasavi": [{
            "studentname": "jason",
            "address": "babli hook",
            "admissionnumber": "77766"

        }, {
            "studentname": "micheal",
            "address": "beverli",
            "admissionnumber": "99989"

        }]
    }
}

const flattenedData = Object.values(jsonData.Colleges).flat(); // defaults to depth 1

console.log(flattenedData);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1zasjw73/

This Code is not working in IE

Comment: `.flat` is not supported in IE, neither is Object.entries.

Comment: Please refer [BrowserCompatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Object.values is **not** supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), neither is [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

You can either include polyfills, or do that in other ways without using neither flat, nor Object.values.

In the below example, I'm just using a nested `.forEach` on `Object.keys`; both are supported from IE9 onwards.

Please note that, if you're targeting IE9, you can't use `const` either. If you're targeting IE11, however, you can.

```js
var jsonData = {
    "Colleges": {
        "GMR": [{
            "studentname": "peter",
            "address": "green woods",
            "admissionnumber": "55667"

        }, {
            "studentname": "paul",
            "address": "antonio",
            "admissionnumber": "66654"

        }],

        "vasavi": [{
            "studentname": "jason",
            "address": "babli hook",
            "admissionnumber": "77766"

        }, {
            "studentname": "micheal",
            "address": "beverli",
            "admissionnumber": "99989"

        }]
    }
}


var res = [];
Object.keys(jsonData.Colleges).forEach(function(cName){
  jsonData.Colleges[cName].forEach(function(college){
    res.push(college);
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function flat () {
 var depth = isNaN(arguments[0]) ? 1 : Number(arguments[0]);

 return depth ? Array.prototype.reduce.call(this, function (acc, cur) {
  if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
   acc.push.apply(acc, flat.call(cur, depth - 1));
  } else {
   acc.push(cur);
  }

  return acc;
 }, []) : Array.prototype.slice.call(this);
};
```

You can use this polyfill function for `.flat()` method.

```
if(!Object.entries) 
    Object.entries = function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(arr, key) {
            arr.push([key, obj[key]]);
            return arr;
        }, []);
    }
```

You can use this polyfill function for `Object.entries()` method.

Comment: Only that would not suffice as neither Object.values is supported in IE and hence it would require a polyfill as well

Comment: I added a polyfill for Object.entries too.